# Issue on Loading Dynamic Data to "DataTables" Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/hvgnzbwq/)**

I am using [this solution](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) to load dynamic data in to `Data Table`. I have to use the Array of Array since I am getting dynamic data from user on font end selection (NO DATABASE Selection).
I am using following code to upload data into the table

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example"></table>
```

and JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    var compareTable = [];
    var compareRow = [];
    var check = "Test";
    var compModelName = "Test";
    var selectedType = "Test";
    var selectedTarget = "Test";
    var selectedROR = "Test";
    var selectedSpecies = "Test";
    var historicDis = "Test";
    var projectsNumber = "Test";
    var projectsCost = "Test";
    var projectsRoads = "Test";
    var projectsPowerline = "Test";
    var projectsPenstock = "Test";
    var mapshow = "Test";

    $("#load").on("click", function () {
        loader();
    });

    function loader() {
        compareRow.push(check);
        compareRow.push(compModelName);
        compareRow.push(selectedType);
        compareRow.push(selectedTarget);
        compareRow.push(selectedROR);
        compareRow.push(selectedSpecies);
        compareRow.push(historicDis);
        compareRow.push(projectsNumber);
        compareRow.push(projectsCost);
        compareRow.push(projectsRoads);
        compareRow.push(projectsPowerline);
        compareRow.push(projectsPenstock);
        compareRow.push(mapshow);
    }

    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "data": compareTable,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Compare" },
             { "title": "Model Name" },
            { "title": "Model Type" },
            { "title": "Energy Target" },
            { "title": "ROR Attribute" },
            { "title": "Species", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Disturbance", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Projects" },
            { "title": "Cost (M$)" },
            { "title": "Roads (Km)" },
            { "title": "Powerlines (Km)", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Penstock (m)", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Map" }
         ]
    } );   
    });
});
```

but as you can see in the Demo it is not functioning when we click on the `"#load"`. Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: you should probably save the return from $('#example').dataTable(); it contains methods you can use to, for example, redraw the table when you update the underlying data.

Comment: Hi dandavis, Thanks for reply I update code as [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/hvgnzbwq/1/) but still not working!

Comment: Something like this?? : http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/hvgnzbwq/5/

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for reply but how about having `compareRow ` not hard coded! I mean something like what I have. is the same process as what you did here?

Comment: Can you please check this http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/hvgnzbwq/6/ it is not loading the Array correctly!